# Infinite degree covering space of a bouquet of circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am having a hard time showing that every finite group is the automorphism group of some infinite degree covering space of a bouquet of circles (rose). Here's what I have done so far:

Let $G = \{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$ be a finite group and construct its Cayley graph $\Gamma$ with respect to some finite set of generators (*e.g.* all the $g_i$'s). Let $B$ be a bouquet of circles where each circle corresponds to a generator. Then we know that there exists a regular covering map $p : \Gamma \to B$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma) \cong G$. We wish to extend $p$ to an infinite degree cover $\tilde{p} : \tilde{\Gamma} \to \tilde{B}$, where $\tilde{B} \supset B$ is a bouquet of circles, such that its automorphism group remains unaltered, that is, $\mathrm{Aut}(\tilde{\Gamma}) \cong G$.

I am unsure how to build such an extension. Is there an easier way to proceed? Is the extension idea any good? Any help or hint would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in order for this to be possible, you need a covering which is not regular. 
Let $\tilde B$ contain one more circle, and let $\tilde{\Gamma}$ be constructed as follows. Take a copy of $\Gamma$ and at every vertex attach a copy of $\mathbb R$ along $0\in \mathbb R$. To each of these new copies of $\mathbb R$, attach a copy of $B$ to each nonzero integer $n\in\mathbb R$. Now map the intervals $[n,n+1]$ in the copies of $\tilde{\Gamma}$ to the extra circle in $\tilde B$, map the copies of $B$ in the obvious way, and map $\Gamma$ by $p$. This is a non-regular covering space, as you can check. Translation along the extra copies of $\mathbb R$ has been killed, which means the automorphisms have to take place inside of $\Gamma$ alone.

**Edit:** A little simpler is to attach an extra circle to $\Gamma$ at all vertices except the basepoint. Attach a copy of $\mathbb R$ at the basepoint to $0\in\mathbb R$, and attach a copy of $B$ to the nonzero integers in $\mathbb R$. The extra circles map onto the extra circle in $\tilde B$ and everything else maps as above.

Comment: Very enlightening!